# Terraform & RDS Postgres: why isn't pg_repack allowed in shared_preload_libraries?

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

[AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Extensions.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.pg_repack) say:

> This extension is supported on RDS for PostgreSQL versions 9.6.3 and higher.

Alas, below error is returned when provisioning RDS instance with this parameters:

```
resource "aws_db_parameter_group" "this" {
  "parameter" {
          name = "shared_preload_libraries"
          value = "pg_stat_statements,auto_explain,pg_repack"
          apply_method = "pending-reboot"
      }
  # ...
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "this" {
  engine_version = "11.12"
  # ...
}
```

> Error: Error modifying DB Parameter Group: InvalidParameterValue: Invalid parameter value: pg_repack for: shared_preload_libraries allowed values are: auto_explain,orafce,pgaudit,pglogical,pg_bigm,pg_hint_plan,pg_prewarm,pg_similarity,pg_stat_statements,pg_transport,plprofiler

The error disappears if `pg_repack` is removed from the above `value` list.

Env:

- terraform 1.3.1
- hashicorp/aws 4.18.0

Comment: Have you tried with newer versions of the AWS provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only [those extensions listed](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-postgresql-resolve-preload-error/) needed to be installed in RDS via the `shared_preload_libraries` setting. As per [the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Extensions.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.pg_repack) on using the `pg_repack` library in RDS, all you need to do is run `CREATE EXTENSION pg_repack;` and it will be made available in your RDS instance.